# How to get subimage with fraction value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, crop

I am using

```
BufferedImage out = image.getSubimage(x,y,w,z)
```

But my x,y,w,h values are in fraction like 22.52

Is there any method for croping(get subimage) where I can use double values???

Comment: x,y,w and z are pixels/dots (x,y, width and height). What's the meaning of 22.52 pixels?

Answer (score 1):

The function parameters refer to pixel values on your computer screen.
You can't access 52-hundredths of a pixel.

Try using `(int) Math.round()` to convert a `double` value to an `int`.

Comment: Or Math.ceil() to round up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As said by others the units are in pixels. As 22.52 "pixels" is tiny, the unit intended must be mm.
Considering a screen with 72 DPI (dots per inch, pixels per inch) a factor 2.83464 (seems wrong) would be needed for pixels. And then rounding.